# how to avoid SOQL query inside for loop?

Tags: apex

I have below code in which there is a SOQL query inside for loop. I have been advised to use map to avoid SOQL in the loop. As i am a beginner in Salesforce I dont know how to do it. Here's my code

```java
private static void assignPreferredTitleCompany(List<Acquisition__c> acqs, Map<Id, Acquisition__c> oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap) {
    String titleUserId = AcquisitionLibrary.assignmentUsersIdMap.get(AcquisitionLibrary.ACQ_DE_TITLE_USER_LAST_NAME);
    String firmName = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Title_User__c = :titleUserId].Id;

    for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
        String oldTitleUser = oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap.get(acq.id).Title_User__c;
        String firmName = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Title_User__c = :acq.Title_User__c].Id;
        if(oldTitleUser == titleUserId && acq.Title_User__c != oldTitleUser)
            acq.Preferred_Title_Company__c = firmName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, you need a Map. This is always true when you have a query inside a loop, or when you have a nested for loop with an if statement.

This is a three-part process: [Aggregate, Query, and Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html).

```
Map<String, Id> titleUserToFirmId = new Map<String, Id>();
// Aggregate
for(Acquisition__c acq: acqs) {
  titleUserToFirmId.put(acq.Title_User__c, null);
}
// Query
// Notice how we query Title_User__c so we can identify each account
for(Account firm: [SELECT Title_User__c FROM Account WHERE Title_User__c = :titleUserToFirmId.keySet()]) {
  titleUserToFirmId.put(firm.Title_User__c, firm.Id);
}
// Update
for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
    String oldTitleUser = oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap.get(acq.id).Title_User__c;
    Id firmId = titleUserToFirmId.get(acq.Title_User__c);
    if(oldTitleUser == titleUserId && acq.Title_User__c != oldTitleUser)
        acq.Preferred_Title_Company__c = firmId;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response.. It just needed minor changes but this aptly covered the logic i was looking for